# About Visa for academic conference in Dubai/Abu-Dhabi

Tags: visas, dubai, uae, emirates, conferences

I am going to a conference in Abu-Dhabi in December.

1. What kind of visa category should I apply for? Will the tourist visa be OK?
2. How many days does it take to get a UAE visa?
3. I am taking my wife and kid as well. What kind of visa do I need to take?
4. For my baby, who is less than a year old, do I need to take any visa at all?

Comment: What’s your nationality?

Comment: See https://www.etihad.com/en-gb/before-you-fly/visas/

Comment: Pakistani. But I am doing PhD in New Zealand

Answer (score 2):

Every passenger that has a passport, needs a visa (if a visa is required at all).

If you do need a visa (it depends on your nationality), then you need the normal tourist visa as there are no specific visas for attending conferences. Visa processing time can take from 2 - 7 business days (depends on when and how you apply).

The best place to start is through your airline. Etihad, Emirates and Flydubai offer visa services that can assist with your application.